# How to optimize a rest API response that call external APIs multiple time and responds list of results?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, httprequest, httpresponse

I have written a rest API that takes a request that is a list (size of this list is dynamic).

Now what my API does is, for each item in the list calls an external API and responds with the collection of all the responses.

Please refer the flow diagram below:

[image]

Now this process is time consuming and response time is too high.

**Note:**

1. This has to be a synchronous process.
2. We cannot implement pagination here.
3. Also we don't want to go for multithreading as it can be an overkill if the number of items is too less and if the number of items is too high it may eat up a lot of resources.

So is there something we can do to reduce this response time?

Comment: Why not decide the thread count based on the number of items?

Comment: how often do you call "My App" endpoint with the same parameters? Maybe you can load some cache with External API data in async path, or just cache your My App responses.

Comment: we do it just once for one unique call because we are saving the response from external API to DB. Next time if we receive the same call we respond with the saved data.

Answer (score 0):

For the solution for your problem I would recommend reactive microservices, that is, how to develop non-blocking synchronous REST APIs and asynchronous event-driven services.

Traditionally, as Java developers, we are used to implementing synchronous
communication using blocking I/O, for example, a RESTful JSON API over HTTP.
Using a blocking I/O means that a thread is allocated from the operating system for the length of the request. If the number of concurrent requests goes up, a server might run out of available threads in the operating system, causing problems ranging from longer response times to crashing servers. Using a microservice architecture typically makes this problem even worse, where typically a chain of cooperating microservices is used to serve a request. The more microservices involved in serving a request, the faster the available threads will be drained.

If a synchronous programming model is preferred, use **reactive frameworks**
that can execute synchronous requests using non-blocking I/O, without
allocating a thread while waiting for a response. This will make the
microservices easier to scale in order to handle an increased workload.

Comment: Your suggestion is good. But I got doubt the reactive programming/architecture helps in improving throughput (ability to process more requests) and cannot help in improving performance of a request processing.  I  believe here this is the requirement.